# Irregular time jumps in a Size vs Time graph of an SpMV algorithm

Tags: c, performance, caching, sparse-matrix, cpu-architecture

I'm testing my code for sizes 1 to 1000 and I'm measuring the time needed for each iteration and I noticed big difference in time, even if the sizes differ by one.

I conducted 7 tests, but I'll only paste 3 here. The x-axis in the pictures represents matrix sizes(N x N), the y-axis represents time in microseconds.

Here is the code snippet I'm testing:

```
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    for (j = row_ptr[i]; j < row_ptr[i + 1]; j++) 
    {
        result[i] += val[j] * x[col_idx[j]];
    }
}
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
// Stop time measurement

interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;
```

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

I tried to find a solution to this, like finding the sizes to fill my L3 Cache and test with those sizes but nothing came out of it.

Why am I getting these irregularities? And also, why am I getting lower time for some larger sizes of matrices?

PS Here's the full [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3eugj0sm3fvxruz/main.c) if someone is interested:

Answer (score 0):

Although the name may lead you to believe that `QueryPerformanceCounter` is measuring the performance of your task, it is actually measuring elapsed time, not the CPU time associated with the current task.

And even if it were measuring CPU time, there are a number of things which can distract the CPU for a few microseconds (or milliseconds in the case of other running tasks grabbing the CPU), including interrupt processing (eg., network traffic), page faults, and TLB flushes. All these various events add a bit of noise to benchmarks; the standard advice is to run your benchmarks many times and remove the outliers before analyzing the data.

Also, before you start running your benchmark, nothing useful will be in the CPUs caches, and the branch prediction will be inaccurate. So the first few benchmark runs will normally be successively faster, as the caches and branch prediction "warms up". (You need to be particularly careful about comparing two different algorithms by running them successively in the same benchmark program. If you don't account for cache-warmup of in-memory data, the first benchmark may appear to be slower than the second one even if they are exactly the same algorithm.)

Finally, there are often tiny differences between core performance in multicore chips, so a switch from one core to another can result in a vertical displacement in the benchmark graph, such as the one you see at approximately N=400 in the first graph.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
What do you suggest I measure the CPU Time with? I tried with numerous functions that I found on SO but I get 0.00... as output.

Comment: @Ascent: I think it's fine to use QPC for measuring, but you need to use a good benchmarking protocol, as I suggest in the answer: first warm up the caches, then do several iterations and discard the outliers (that is, the iterations which took far longer than any other).